# Como instalar GCC y G++ en GNU/Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

Mi pregunta es: como instalar **gcc y g++** en **GNU/Linux**  (ubuntu)

Me gustaría saber el comando de instalación específicamente, y la instalación paso a paso. :D

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Ubuntu puedes hacer:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
```

y

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Eso va a activar los dos paquetes (ambos forman parte de `gcc`).

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta.